# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/vue.js?v=535663ae' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using a js framework known as [griptape](https://docs.vue.griptapejs.com)(used for blockchain). I'm getting this error when trying to use the vue router.

```
import Vue from "vue"; //Error **does not provide an export named 'default'**
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue"),
  },
];

 const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});
export default router;
```

while my `vue.d.ts` file looks like this

```
import { CompilerOptions } from '@vue/compiler-dom';
import { RenderFunction } from '@vue/runtime-dom';

export declare function compile(template: string | HTMLElement, options?: CompilerOptions): RenderFunction;

export * from "@vue/runtime-dom";

export { }
```

`router.d.ts` file look like this [image]

Comment: may I ask why you are defining those typing yourself?

Comment: having the same problem, could it relate to the Vue version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are using `Vue 3`. You should check your `vue-router` version. If you just run `npm i vue-router` now, the version should be "^3.5.3". Try to use `npm i vue-router@next` to install newer version.

Then export router like this:

```js
import {createRouter, createWebHistory}  from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
    {
        path:'/',
        name:"Home",
        component:()=>import('./pages/Home.vue')
    }
    ,
    {
        path:'/about',
        name:"About",
        component:()=>import('./pages/About.vue')
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history:createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Could you please give us a cdn solution as well?

Answer (score -2):

You technically didn't ask a question I will try to explain the error. Your error states what you try to do, importing a default export from the module 'vue' which doesn't exist.

```
// some ts file
import Vue from "vue";

// the module
export default {}
```

If there should be a named export called 'Vue' you should write it as follows: `import { Vue } from 'vue'`

references:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#default-exports

Comment: This answer isn't necessarily wrong, but I think the root issue is the fact that OP appears to be attempting to generate the Vue type definitions by hand. The correct way to import Vue is indeed `import Vue from 'vue'`.

Comment: @Matt U Thanks for your addition, you’re absolutely right. Maybe can OP elaborate on how Vue was added to the project, was it through ViteJS? In that case OP might need to import vue through the vue-class-component library (see docs https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript-compiler-options)