# How do I reference the Vue instance in Vite?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm getting started with Vue 3 and Vite. How do I reference the Vue instance? I'm used to doing...

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

but if I do this in my Vue3/Vite project, there's no default export in the vue module, so...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/vue.js?v=d734dbd3' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I'm clearly having the same problem as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69013483/1585345). I want to do things like Vue.config, Vue.observable(), Vue.set(). There's something very basic that I'm missing. Anyone ?

[image: What is this?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no longer a global instance of `Vue` available in Vue3:
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#global-api

You have to add these things to the app you created with `createApp`